# Share post to facebook in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Thanks in Advance . Here am trying facebook share functionality ..It works .. But image of the page not showing while sharing.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=nexevo-demo.in/gopi/post/home" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> </a>
```

If anybody Knows about that means Give a advice .

Comment: Hard to know without that information you given us. Maybe css issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing error for showing the thumbnail of page please ensure you are using the og tags. og tags tell facebook which photo need to place on post thumb and what should be the description for that.
It will go like this:-

```html
<meta property="og:url"           content="www.yoursiteurl/page.com" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="Website name" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="Put the title here" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="Give a long description here" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="www.yoursite.com/urpicurl" />
```

Comment: <meta property="og:url"           content="http://nexevo-demo.in/gopi/post" />       
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />       
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Beopheric" />      
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Blog site" />       
  <meta property="og:image"         content="<?php echo base_url() ; ?>/assets_ui/images/blog.png" />